# Inner class within application class, is it right?

Tags: java, static, inner-classes, android

I'm working in a application which has many activities and most of the activities share more than one objects, So I created MyApplication class by extending android Application class to store selected objects to share. But I feel quit uncomfortable while accessing those objects inside provider/helper classes b'coz context is needed in providers to **get instance of Application**.

So I planned to create static class called SelectionProvider inside MyApplication class to store selected objects, then I can access those in static way without create instance to MyApplication.

MyApplication class with static inner class as follows

```
class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static final String TAG = "MyApplication";



    public static class SelectionProvider {
        private static UserObj userObj;
        private static TownObj townObj;
        private static StoreObj storeObj;

        public static UserObj getUserObj() {
            return userObj;
        }

        public static setUserObj(UserObj userObj) {
            this.userObj = userObj;
        }

        public static TownObj getTownObj() {
            return townObj;
        }

        public static setTownObj(TownObj townObj) {
            this.townObj = townObj;
        }

        public static StoreObj getStoreObj() {
            return storeObj;
        }

        public static setStoreObj() {
            this.storeObj = storeObj;
        }
    }
}
```

**Is it right approach? if not why?**

**Will reside the selected objects** (which are stored in inner class) **in entire application life or will it destroyed anywhere?**

Comment: What do you mean that you require context to instantiate the application?  You should not be instantiating the application object at all but rather calling getApplication();  What are you doing to instantiate your Application Object?

Comment: 1. it is one of many right approaches. 2. the entire application life.

Comment: @mjsalinger, thank you, I updated my question, I'm not creating instance of application, just getting instance of application from activity and pass it to providers. That was I mean it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method or a static value elsewhere should work fine and last for the lifetime of the application as long as you don't have [multiple processes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes) running that need access to this object.  If that's the case, you should use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to handle transactions.

Comment: thank you Andy, I updated my question, I'm not creating instance of application, just getting instance of application from activity and pass it to providers.

Answer (score 0):

I would not design it as an inner class.  I would create SelectionProvider (and any other classes you need) as its own separate class, and instantiate it in your MyApplication class' onCreate method.

You should not instantiate the application object as it can be accessed at any time by calling getApplication() and casting it to your application class (e.g. (MyApplication)getApplication();  Then you can access any objects created by the class.

If data persistence is an issue with these classes, consider storing their values in SQLLite or as a Shared Preference, as Android may terminate your application at any time when it is in the background if it needs the resources.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a singleton class of my own:

```
public class Data {

    /* Start of singleton block */

    private static Data data = new Data();

    private Data(){
    }

    public static Data getInstance(){
    }

    /* End of singleton block */ 

    private SelectionProvider selectionProvider;

    public SelectionProvider getSelectionProvider(){
       return selectionProvider;
    }

    /* other necessary methods (get, set) and classes below */

}
```

This way you can access your objects with  `Data.getInstance().getSelectionProvider()`. 
This will be available during an active application, though you might want to build in some persistant storing of your data for when the user leaves the app for some time to come back later:

```
public SelectionProvider getSelectionProvider(){
    if(selectionProvider == null)
        selectionProvider = readSelectionProviderFromPersistantStorage();

    return selectionProvider;
}
```

Comment: thank you Niek, previously I'm also create my own singleton class, but my is destroyed if application kept ideal for sometime from the activity which is not use that singleton object. So I cant get my selected objects, that's why moved my selection provider to Application class.

Comment: That is when you can use persistant storage as noted in the answer. Save it to a file or preferences to fetch it back later